# Does it matter if you turn off the monitor while timing graphics code?

Tags: graphics

I'm fairly certain that it shouldn't matter since the graphics card is still executing the commands given by the CPU and sending the framebuffer to a monitor that is simply not listening. However, I'm not sure if the graphics card doesn't detect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most configurations I can't imagine that it would matter.  But when my laptop is docked, I use the laptop screen as a secondary monitor.  If I switch off the primary monitor with it still docked then it auto switches to the laptop as the primary (and only monitor).  In that situation it must need some processing power so would imagine it would affect the timings, etc.